# How to read from pipe using a MappedByteBuffer

Tags: java, pipe, nio

I want to read a file, which name is passed by command line arguments. I'm concerned about reading speed, so I'm trying to use `MappedByteBuffer`.

```
FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
System.out.println("fileStream.available(): " + fileStream.available());

FileChannel channel = fileStream.getChannel();
System.out.println("channel.size(): " + channel.size());

MappedByteBuffer buffer =
    channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size());
System.out.println("buffer.limit(): " + buffer.limit());

for (int i = 0; i < buffer.limit(); i++) {
    // process buffer.get() ...
}
```

It works well with regular files, but it doesn't read data from pipes (e.g. from `/dev/fd/63`). When I run `java Program <(perl -0777pe '$_=$_ x 1000' jfdctint.c)` I get the following output:

```
fileStream.available(): 65536
channel.size(): 0
buffer.limit(): 0
```

So there is nothing to read from buffer. I'm struggling to find out if `MappedByteBuffer` is compatible with pipe. How to read the data and does is make sense to map `FileChannel` onto `MappedByteBuffer` for a pipe at all?

Comment: Try using regular FileChannels or even InputStreams first.  The speed may surprise you.  If you still find optimization necessary, try using a [direct](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocateDirect-int-) ByteBuffer.

Comment: @VGR Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: This does not make sense. MappedByteBuffer is for random access to existing files, and pipes are sequential and initially empty.